# Python. csv to usable dict

Tags: python, function, csv, dictionary

im trying to build a dictonary form a csv-file and then to give another function this dictonary but Python forms it to some kind of object and i cant handle that with my knowledge. Output of the print is: <class 'csv.DictReader'> <csv.DictReader object at 0x00000172BBB1CCD0>

```
def load_cities():
"""
Read CSV-Data from File into a Dictonary.
"""
    city_dict = {}
       
    with open(CURRENT_DIR / FILE, mode = "r", encoding = "utf-8") as fin:
        city_dict = csv.DictReader(fin)
        print(type(city_dict), city_dict)

    sort_by_name(city_dict)
```

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)? That includes examples of how to use the `DictReader` class.

Comment: Please, fix the indentation of your code.

Comment: If i read that correctly both CSV-Reader and CSV-Writer create objects. I dont need a object only a dictonary with key-Value pairs to give it to another function. The CSV file have a header.

Answer (score 0):

> csv.DictReader creates an object that operates like a regular reader
> but maps the information in each row to a dict whose keys are given by
> the optional fieldnames parameter.

How does your data looks like? If you want to get a list of dicts (for each row), you can do:

```
print(list(city_dict))
```

If you want to create one dictionary, you can create it like this

```
print({row[0]:row[1] for row in csv.reader(fin)})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had modified a solution from another problem and this worked. But can the dictReader build usable dictonaries?

```
def load_cities():
"""
Read CSV-Data from File into a Dictonary.
"""
    results = []

    file = open("worldcities_short.csv", mode="r", encoding="utf-8")
    cities_string = file.read()
    file.close()

    input_list = cities_string.split("\n") 
    for row in input_list:
        words = row.split(",")
        results.append(words)
    header = results.pop(0)
    city_dict = {}
    for row in results:
        first_name = row[0]
        city_dict[first_name] = dict(zip(header, row))
    print(city_dict)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).